# VueJS block activity on not active browser tab

Tags: javascript, vue.js, browser, settimeout

I have a web app written in Typescript and VueJS that execute a collection of tasks (ajax requests) and to track the whole process (and to execute one task after another) I use a Vue instance as bus to notify changes between components.
If the user open a new browser tab, the process stop. If the user come back, the process resumes.

The issue is present in Firefox and in Chrome.
I put in my code a simple window.setInterval to log every 2 seconds an 'Hello' and...surprise I have an 'Hello' every 2 seconds without any temporal 'hole'.
I see a very old issue in github for a similar situation: https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/76 but seems to be too old to be this.

I expect that the process doesn't stop but continues without interruptions..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/background_tabs

> Background tabs can have a dramatic negative effect on browser performance, especially on battery life. To mitigate this, Chrome has been placing various restrictions on background tabs for the last several years. Recently there’s been a number of efforts to make further improvements, and this document gives an overview of the Chrome policy. This document focuses on describing current policies in Chrome 57. Long-term strategy and further plans can be found in this document.

https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6172836527865856

> As an intervention we want to limit how much CPU a background page is allowed to use and to throttle timer queues when this limit is violated. Current target is that background page CPU load level should be under 1%.